# Dealing with randomly generated JSON

Tags: json, jackson

Pleaseeeeeeee help me, it's been three weeks since I turned around to found how make POJO jackson with this json, random is randonm keyname.

{
   "a": {
     "b1": "1",
     "b2": "{ 
        "random" : {
            "c1": "10"
            "c2": "20"
        }
    }
 }

Somebody can help me ?

Comment: you should add a tag for the programming language you use, since you talk about POJO, I believe this is Java.  also, which library/parser are you using? there quite a few java json parsers

Comment: Yes it is java. I'll with use jackson, I'm trying use JsonProperty and Class nested.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the online utility
http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/

Answer (score 0):

You can use Jackson's `@JsonAnySetter` annotation to direct all random/variable keys to one method and there you can assign/handle them as you wish:

```
public class Pojo
{
    // known/fixed properties
    public String b1;
    public String b2;
    ...

    // unknown/variable properties will go here
    @JsonAnySetter
    public void setRandom(String key, Object value)
    {
        System.out.println("variable key = '" + key + "'");
        System.out.println("value is of type = " + value.getClass());
        System.out.println("value toString = '" + value.toString() + "'");
    }
}
```

in the case of the sample input, the output is:

```
variable key = 'random'
value is of type = class java.util.LinkedHashMap
value toString = '{c1=10, c2=20}'
```